# MongoDB aggregation - $regexMatch on array field

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I'm using Mongo's [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) operator to find documents where at least part of a field matches the pattern, and this works fine for root-level fields. But how do I use it with array fields? I want to return a match if at least one of the array elements matches the pattern.

For example, let's say the collection has these two documents:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ff6335c1570ba63ca5ac21e"),
  "requirements": [
    {
      "description": "Bachelor of Science required for this blah blah blah",
      "code": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "description": "Also much experience in JavaScript blah",
      "code": "XYZ"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ff6335b1570ba63ca5abefb"),
  "requirements": [
    {
      "description": "Master of Arts WANTED NOW!",
      "code": "TTT"
    },
    {
      "description": "5+ experience required in C++",
      "code": "QQQ"
    }
  ]
}
```

and something like this pipeline

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
  { $match:
     { $expr:
        { $regexMatch: { 
          input: '$requirements.description', 
          regex: /^.*?\bblah blah blah\b.*?$/im 
        } } 
     } 
  }
])
```

should return *just* the first document since its first element inside `requirements` matches on `description` containing "blah blah blah"
("Bachelor of Science required for this blah blah blah").

However this just throws me an error saying '$regexMatch needs `input` to be of type string'. And replacing it with `$requirements[0].description` doesn't work either.

So is there a way to regex match array fields in Mongo?

Comment: what is your expectation? it should return a single matching document? it should return score? can you show expected result,

Comment: I updated the example for clarity -- but the expectation is that it returns any documents that match the pattern (in this case, having "blah blah blah" as part of the description for at least one of their requirements)

Comment: Just use $regex operator, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mQmOpgahODL)

Comment: oh wow that's so much simpler -- is there a way to do the same thing with $addFields instead of $match to add a score field too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$regexMatch` allows only string input `requirements` having array It requires to iterate loop array values,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `description`, check condition if expression match then return score otherwise return initial value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      score: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$requirements.description",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $regexMatch: {
                      input: "$$this",
                      regex: "blah blah blah"
                    }
                  },
                  true
                ]
              },
              50,
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UjorDeK0t3d)

---

If you want filter documents the simply try `$regex` in `$match` stage,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "requirements.description": {
        $regex: "blah blah blah"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mQmOpgahODL)

Comment: Tried too hard to make regexMatch work for an array of objects, when regex was right there :') Thanks